Stored function for finding exact string match is always returning false
I am trying to create a stored function that checks to see if an exact string has been used already. This function that I have created always returns FALSE though, even when I set the RETURNS datatype to INT and declared a test_variable. PLEASE HELP!
I have tried everything I could think of, but I am a beginner.
USE ap;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_glaccounts_description;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION test_glaccounts_description
(
    account_description_param   VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT account_number FROM general_ledger_accounts WHERE account_description_param = account_description)) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL test_glaccounts_description('Accounting');


Does the select when run on it's own find anything?

Btw you call a procedure but invoke a function. You must have a procedure with the same name which you should publish.

The correct way to test the function is with SELECT test_glaccounts_description('Accounting');

A function whose result is dependent on table contents shouldn't be declared DETERMINISTIC.
